# Three.js: Custom attributes on Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I have been using Three for a while now, but I have gotten kind of stuck on something for the past few days. I am trying to pass a custom attribute to my shader which I would like to update quite often. The shader is added as a ShaderMaterial to my mesh. The problem I am having with it though is that I noticed a few versions ago, Three redid the way it handles attributes. Instead of having them in the material, you have them on your geometry. As far as I am able to understand though, a normal geometry can't handle custom attributes, which kind of puts me in a bad situation since I was relying pretty heavily on all conveniences it provides. I have tried using a BufferGeometry, but that just ended up in confusion and frustration when I couldn't get my UV map (which I am constantly updating) correctly onto it. Is there any alternative to the BufferGeometry approach if you want custom attributes or maybe (although less desirable) a way to apply my UV's correctly onto it? Is there a reason why a normal geometry can't have custom attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cou convert your geometry to a buffer geometry then set its custom attributes, thus keeping the best of both worlds. This will save you the trouble of dealing with buffergeometry uvs as you seem to be asking. The uvs should be passed over.

Like so :

`var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );`

Comment: I didn't actually know that BufferGeometry also had a fromGeometry function. I thought it was exclusive to the normal Geometry. Anyway, I did forget to mention, but I am updating my UV's pretty much on every render, so I don't think this would perform well enough.

Comment: You may update the UVs of your BufferGeometry on the fly too. [Check this fiddle out](https://jsfiddle.net/Pisha/4ud3c22u/2/)

I created a cube from a BoxGeometry, which I then used to get a BufferGeometry from it. In the animate() function : write your UVs update sequence and apply it to the right vertices. Don't forget to update the uvs. Does it help ?

Comment: While this was quite difficult to implement, I eventually managed to figure out how the arrays are put together and from that managed to loop through all the "faces", assigning their appropriate UV's, generating reasonable results.